# How to release an iPhone app that uses an external 3rd party library?

Tags: iphone, compilation, release, application-loader

We're using a 3rd party library in our iPhone app and when we build it for Release & Device, we're able to find the application in the expected folder (Release-iphoneos), but we also find the library in that same folder.

When uploading the application, do we have to do anything extra with the external library, or is it by default included in the iPhone application?

We do have it included in the Targets -> Application -> Link Binary With Libraries, but we're not sure if that's enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general test is, if you've linked the library and included it in your project, and your app runs on a Device in any mode (Debug or Distribution), then all will be well for the release build.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .app itself! It's just a .zip file that you can open. Change the file ending to .zip and unpack it. You can see if the library is included or not.

[edit:] sorry, i mixed .ipa (which is a combined format for ad-hoc distribution and app-store upload) and the .app
But you can still check that. Use build and archive and export for ad-hoc distribution. (save to file) that will give you an .ipa - if the library is not included in the .app itself, it should be in the .ipa (but I doubt that...)